# "Впрочем, неважно – в спектакле ли, в фильме – всегда оставляешь кусочек себя" - что со знаками?

Tags: пунктуация

> Театр требует большей отдачи сил, большей концентрации внимания, актёр
>   за два с половиной часа проживает человеческую жизнь.
>   В кино, даже если точно знаешь, что нужно делать, многое зависит от
>   режиссёра. **Впрочем, неважно – в спектакле ли, в фильме – всегда
>   оставляешь кусочек себя.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При двух тире здесь не находится ожидаемая вставка; не хватает обобщающего указания, где кусочек остаётся (видимо, в том, над чем работаешь, и ряд не закончен).

> Впрочем, неважно, в спектакле, в фильме ли – *в этом* всегда оставляешь
>   кусочек себя.

Answer (score 1):

(Пытаюсь аккуратно, без вредительства автору.)
В первом предложении (вместо последней запятой) я бы поставила тире:

*Театр требует б**о**льшей отдачи сил, б**о**льшей концентрации внимания —* [потому что, так как, ведь] *актёр за два с половиной часа проживает человеческую жизнь.*

Третье предложение искручено хитро.

1. *В спе**ктакле ли*** — неудобно читается и произносится.
2. "Отрываем" пояснительную вставку, получается:
   *Впрочем, неважно, всегда оставляешь кусочек себя.*

Возникает вопрос: где этот кусочек остается? Или в чём?

Я бы предложила такое оформление:
**Впрочем, неважно – в спектакле или в фильме, – в них всегда оставляешь кусочек себя.**

Или такое:
**Впрочем, неважно – в спектакле или в фильме, – в них всегда остаётся кусочек тебя самого.**